# What does -> mean in the context of this function call?

Tags: php, function

```
$title = l(
    $comment->subject,
    comment_node_url(),
    array('fragment' => "comment-$comment->cid")
  );
```

Ok, so $title is the l() function, and from what I'm reading, I am passing the $comment->subject argument to l() - is that correct?

What does $comment->subject mean? I'm looking all over and not understanding what it means. Is it an operator of some sort?

Sorry if this is a simple question - I just can't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Look under the "classes & objects" section of the above linked question. Also see [the PHP docs on objects & classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Comment: You guys may have downvoted me, but that "reference - what does this symbol mean in PHP?" is just about the most fantastically useful thing I've ever seen. Thank you!

Comment: OOP! learn it! It will be worth it..

Answer (score 1):

It's just an operate that indicates that "subject" is a property of $comment. You can read a bit more on the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Comment: So it works similarly to an associative array?

Comment: That is an utterly bizarre choice of link. I presume you didn't realise it's the documentation for Service Data Objects?

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Don't confuse objects and arrays! Both are complex data structures, but objects are a much more advanced concept.

Comment: @lonesomeday Oops, it appears in my Google haste I linked to something a little too broad. I've fixed it now.